# Wordpress new user goes directly to admin panel

Tags: wordpress

I have created a wordpress site where users can register to post blogs. Problem is, after registering and logging in, the users goes directly to wp-admin panel. This shouldn't be the behavior.

How can I prevent logged in users from accessing wp-admin panel?

Please help.

Comment: Have you set up the **New User Default Role** field properly? E.g. "Subscriber"...

Comment: yes, but should it be the behavior of a site? I mean, why should the users see that top menu of wordpress with dashboard.

Comment: I think that's how WP's designed it to be. I just tried it oout and created a *Subscriber Only* user with which I logged in and the only visible option then is the *Profile* page from the whole Dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

This will also keep everyone that is not an administrator out of the backend.

Place this at the top of your functions.php file.

```
<?php
if(is_admin() && !current_user_can('administrator'))
{
    wp_redirect( home_url(),302);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Just replace home_url() with what ever url you want them to go to after logging in.

Ramon: 
Changelog: changed 301 redirect to 302 redirect to fix browser caching issue when using multiple accounts ( one having adminstrator rights ).
If you did not log in at first and later on you login when being admin your browser will most likely remember your redirect, as per default this is a 301.

Answer (score 1):

Download this plugin, http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/.

Install and activate the plugin, the user will not see the wp-admin login page from now on. Also to prevent the admin dashboard access, go to Setting->Theme My Login. Under the General->Modules tab, Enable Custom Redirection.

Now in the Redirection tab, for different roles you can set a custom landing page, which could be set to point to your homepage. So, after login, he will be directed to your homepage.

And use this small hack to hide the admin bar on top of the screen:
 Go to Appearance->Editor->functions.php

Add this snippet somewhere:

```
//Snippet Begins
if (!current_user_can('administrator')) :
show_admin_bar(false);
endif;
//Snippet Ends
```

And there you go. :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? This will redirect wp-admin for anyone (!) but administrator users.
http://www.mijnpress.nl/blog/deny-wp-admin-for-non-administrator-users/